# NBSP or Blank Space in XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been creating "blank" text views when I want to make a space in my android XML file.

For example, my linear layout activity looks like this:

[image]

So that it creates a space between the textview that says "REGISTRATION" and the next text view that says "First Name."

Is there another way of doing this?  I feel like this makes my code sloppy.

Here is my code:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tbl_result"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:text="Register an Account"
/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/blankspace"

/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:text="First Name"
/>

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/first" 
/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:text="Last Name"
/>

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/last" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tbl_result"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
android:text="Register an Account"
/>

/>
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
// set ur margin here instead of putting one view
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:text="First Name"
/>

<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/first" 
android:layout_margin
/>

<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/last" 
 />
```